# Return products where there was no sales for month

Tags: sql, t-sql

How can I return records where I did not have sales for a month e.g July 2004?

User will supply a date say July 2004 then I need to see the products where there was no sales.

```
SELECT 

 DP.ProductID
,DP.Name
,FS.OrderDate
,FS.OrderQty
,FS.OrderAmount

FROM dbo.DimProduct AS DP

LEFT JOIN dbo.FactSales as FS on FS.ProductID = DP.ProductID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  DP.*
FROM    dbo.DimProduct AS DP
        LEFT JOIN dbo.FactSales as FS 
            ON  FS.ProductID = DP.ProductID AND
                DATENAME(month, FS.OrderDate) = 'July' AND
                YEAR(FS.OrderDate) = 2004
WHERE   FS.ProductID IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this solve your problem:

```
SELECT 

 DP.ProductID
,DP.Name
,FS.OrderDate
,FS.OrderQty
,FS.OrderAmount

FROM dbo.DimProduct AS DP
LEFT JOIN dbo.FactSales as FS on FS.ProductID = DP.ProductID 

WHERE FS.OrderAmount == 0
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  DP.*
FROM    dbo.DimProduct AS DP
WHERE   NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                     FROM   dbo.FactSales AS FS
                     WHERE  FS.ProductID = DP.ProductID
                            AND DATENAME(month, FS.OrderDate) = 'July'
                            AND YEAR(FS.OrderDate) = 2004 )
```